# Pass value within snowflake's javascript procedure

Tags: javascript, sql, procedure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible in Snowflake dwh to retrive SQL query result and pass it as a variable to the next query within same procedure?

I'm trying to attempt %ROWCOUNT, CURSOR case and got stuck with below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PASS_VAR_IN_JS()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE javascript
  AS
    $$
    var command = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ATTRIBUTE = 'Value'";
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: command} );
    var result1 = stmt.execute();
    return result1.getColumnName(3); //this returns column name
    var col_name = result1.getColumnName(3); //save column name to variable

    //pass the column name to the query
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA WHERE COLUMN_NAME = ;", binds:[col_name]});

    $$;
```

```
UPDATE - working code that passes one result to another query
<pre>
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE szpotma_rowcount()
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
as
$$
  var command = `SELECT ATTR1 FROM TABLE1 LIMIT 1`; 
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: command} );
  var rs = stmt.execute(), col_name ;

  if (rs.next()) {
    col_name = rs.getColumnValue(1);
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
        sqlText: `SELECT STATUS FROM TABLE_STATUS WHERE ATTR1 = :1`, binds: [col_name]});

    //view second query results
    rs = stmt.execute();    
    rs.next()
    return rs.getColumnValue(1);
  }
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

You can do with just:

```
  var command = `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ATTRIBUTE = 'Value'`;
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: command} );
  var rs = stmt.execute(), col_name ;
  if (rs.next()) {
    col_name = rs.getColumnValue(3);

    stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
        sqlText: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = :1`, 
          binds: [col_name]
    });
  }
```

I've listed up various ways to pull data from a result set in:
[How to use Show Command in Stored Procedures - Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821740/how-to-use-show-command-in-stored-procedures-not-working/58823462#58823462)

[**Copied from above**]:

If you have multiple columns, the code becomes slightly more complicated:

```
  var result = [], row, col;
  while (rs.next()) {
    row = [];
    for (col = 1; col <= stmt.columnCount; col++)
      row.push(rs.getColumnValue(col));
    result.push(row);
  }
```

Hardcore JavaScript programmers might compress this to:

```
var result = [], cols = Array.from({ length: stmt.columnCount }, (v, i) => i + 1);
while (rs.next()) result.push(cols.map(c => rs.getColumnValue(c)));
```

A final variant where the first result row contains the column names and the following rows contain the data from the result set, accessible as result[row][column]:

```
var result =
    [ Array.from({ length: stmt.columnCount }, (v, i) => stmt.getColumnName(i + 1)) ];
while (rs.next()) result.push(result[0].map(cn => rs.getColumnValue(cn)));
```

Comment: To give more detail, I'm looking to recreate ROWCOUNT looping as in PL/SQL, T-SQL

Comment: I've included some more examples above.  There is no equivalent of cursor%ROWCOUNT in Snowflake, but after executing the query, stmt.rowCount (undocumented) contains the number of rows in the result set.

Comment: I don't full get how to code the moment of passing the first query result into another query. Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: var sql_command = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 LIMIT 10;";
    var sql_command2 = "SELECT ATTR1, ATTR2 FROM TABLE_2 WHERE    ATTR2= '';";
    
    var statement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command} );
    var resultSet = statement.execute(); col_name ;
    

    if (resultSet.next()) {
    col_name = resultSet.getColumnValue(1);
    
    //how to insert above value to the second statement?
    statement2 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command2} );

Comment: I've expanded the ellipsis [...] from my first version at the top of my answer. You use a positional parameter in the 2nd query (:1 in this case) which is an index into the binds[] array of values (index starting at 1)

Comment: I added few lines after second SQL code to actualy display the results. `    //to return value from above query
    rs = stmt.execute();    
    rs.next()
    return rs.getColumnValue(1);`. First row from the first query did get passed to the second one.

Comment: How could we modify the code to display second query results if first passed 10 rows of one column?

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this, but perhaps the easiest way is to combine the two queries into one.  Why does it have to be two queries? I think you are maybe trying to emulate code from some other system like Oracle, but it is impossible to guess what that code might be.

Comment: Exactly - I wanted for practice reacreate classic PL/SQL behaviour. Positional parameter (`1) made this clear for me. Thanks!